# How to z-rotate two SKSpriteNodes together as if one?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

How can I group two SKSpriteNodes together so that I can z-rotate them as if they are one?  Let's say one SKSpriteNode is a rope and the other is a ball attached to the end of the rope.  How can I make it look like they swing together?  What would be the SKAction to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Put them both in a SKNode and rotate the SKNode (around a certain anchor point)

   ```
   SKNode *container = [[SKNode alloc] init];
   [container addChild:ballSprite];
   [container addChild:ropeSprite];
   container.zRotation = someValue;
   ```
2. Or rotate them separately and them move them so it looks as if they were rotated together.

Comment: Can you post an example of how to nest the two SKSpriteNodes into one SKNode?

Comment: Updated answer. You will of course have to update the positions of the ball and the rope, because now you have to define them in the coordinate space of the container node.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution but here is how i have added SKSpriteNodes to a SKNode (container). containerArray contains the nodes that should be added. The newSpriteName (NSString) is used when deciding if the sprite is displayed with it's front side or back side.

```
// Add a container
_containerNode = [SKNode node]; 
_containerNode.position = _theParentNodePosition;
_containerNode.name = @"containerNode";
[_background addChild:_containerNode];

for (SKNode *aNode in containerArray) {

        if (![aNode.name isEqualToString:@"background"] && ![aNode.name isEqualToString:@"title1"] && ![aNode.name isEqualToString:@"title2"]) {
            // Check if "back" sprite should be added or the front face
            if ([[aNode.name substringFromIndex:[aNode.name length] - 1] isEqualToString:@"b"]) {
                newSpriteName = @"back";
            } else {
                newSpriteName = aNode.name;
            }

            // Prepare the new node
            SKSpriteNode *newNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:newSpriteName];
            newNode.name = aNode.name;
            newNode.zPosition = aNode.zPosition;
            newNode.position = CGPointMake(aNode.position.x - _theParentNodePosition.x, aNode.position.y - _theParentNodePosition.y);

            // Delete the old node
            SKNode *deleteNode = [_background childNodeWithName:aNode.name];
            [deleteNode removeFromParent];

            // Add the new node
            [_containerNode addChild:newNode];
        }
    }
```

And then do a rotation as DrummerB suggested